# Load balancing with one server and IIS7(.5)

Tags: iis-7, load-balancing

Is it possible to configure loadbalancing on one server with IIS7?

What I would like is to have three applications in IIS7 (sites). One site should forward the requests to the other two sites (loadbalanced).

Problem is that at a customer of ours loadbalancing is used (with virtual servers). We on the other hand do not have (yet) a virtual environment and only one buildserver.

(maybe using Application Request Routing module?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest running a load balancer in a VM on your server. Real load balancers do a lot more than redirect requests, and developing web applications to work properly when balanced raises a number of unique issues.

There are a number of open source load balancing programs (in fact, many commercial load balancers are just nicely packaged versions of open source load balancers). Also, most require very little RAM (if that is a consideration).

StackOverflow uses [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/).